# Windows using python 2.7 rather than 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, bash, atom-editor

I can't get windows to use python 3 as default.

I have both versions of python (2.7 & 3.6) installed on my windows 10 pc. I installed python 3 from python.org and ticked the add to PATH box. I've spent a week on and off looking for solutions to getting Bash and Atom to use python 3 as default, including:

- changing the environmental path order,
- reinstalling python3 (so far three times!),
- using `$ python3.6` (or variations of this text I've found online) in git,
- configuring atom-python-run to run python3 (this just flashes a python window, nothing further happens),
- Bash out put:

  $ python --version
  Python 2.7.17
- I downloaded the ubuntu for windows app. This displays the following:

  python3 --version
  Python 3.6.7.

I'm struggling to come up with other ideas that could work (even with the hours of Googling). If anyone could help I'd be grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: Uninstall 2.7? :-)

Comment: I was worried it would be used for something else on my pc. Is there anything it could effect that you can think of? Otherwise, I'm happy to

Comment: Well, I don't know what's on your PC. Of course there *could* be something that uses it.

Comment: If uninstalling 2.7 causes a problem, you can always reinstall it.

Comment: This is one reason why virtual environments (and similar tools) are great.

Comment: Open the system environment variable editor, and modify the user and system "Path" values to prioritize Python 3. Keep in mind that the final `PATH` environment variable consists of concatenating the system and user "Path" values, and the OS searches `PATH` in order from beginning to end, so the system "Path" value takes precedence over the user value.

Comment: I've uninstalled python 2.7. No problems so far. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question is why do you have both versions. Then here is your anwser for your question. You can simply just uninstall 2.7, and use 3.6 for the project. When you need 2.7 just simply reinstall it.

You could also try to find a software that will just turn off python 2.7, but sadly I dont know of such software.

Another thing is just right your python file, change dir into the project. Then do the command `python3 pythonFileName.py` in your console, and it would run the project using python3.

Hope this helps! If you have any questions feel free to comment on this anwser.

Comment: Thanks. I uninstalled 2.7. Has fixed it and don't seem to have any problems so far.